# JSF Different Views for different user´s permissions

Tags: jsf, phaselistener

I am trying to implement user control in my JSF Application.
I need different pages for users with different permissions.

What´s the best way to do it?

One idea I had is making a PhaseListener that redirects the user to correct page but I dont like the idea of testing strings in the request recived.

Comment: The easiest way I know is to use Primefaces EL extensions for UI authorization [link](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/primefaces-el-extensions-for-ui-authorization/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Ravi answered.
'The easiest way I know is to use Primefaces EL extensions for UI authorization'